# SCAPY send packet error OSError: [Errno 97] Address family not supported by protocol

Tags: python, sockets, scapy

I hit the below error when trying to send packet using:

- Ubuntu: release 18.04
- Python: 3.6.6
- scapy version: 2.4.0

```py
>>> send(IP(dst="192.168.1.1")/ICMP())
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-8333be02b5c1> in <module>
----> 1 send(IP(dst="192.168.1.1")/ICMP())

~/scapy/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scapy/sendrecv.py in send(x, inter, loop, count, verbose, realtime, return_packets, socket, *args, **kargs)
    298      [socket=None]) -> None"""
    299     if socket is None
--> 300         socket = conf.L3socket(*args, **kargs)
    301     return __gen_send(socket, x, inter=inter, loop=loop, count=count, verbose=verbose,
    302                       realtime=realtime, return_packets=return_packets)

~/scapy/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scapy/arch/linux.py in __init__(self, iface, type, promisc, filter, nofilter, monitor)
    405     def __init__(self, type = ETH_P_ALL, filter=None, promisc=None, iface=None, nofilter=0):
    406         self.type = type
--> 407         self.ins = socket.socket(socket.AF_PACKET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.htons(type))
    408         self.ins.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_RCVBUF, 0)
    409         if iface:

/usr/lib/python3.6/socket.py in __init__(self, family, type, proto, fileno)
    142         # constructor of _socket.socket converts the given argument to an
    143         # integer automatically.
--> 144         _socket.socket.__init__(self, family, type, proto, fileno)
    145         self._io_refs = 0
    146         self._closed = False

OSError: [Errno 97] Address family not supported by protocol
```

Is there anything that might cause this on a fresh install of Scapy?

Comment: I suggest visiting [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in order to get a better insight on how to ask a solid question. Additionally, some code, errors, and a slightly better explanation is necessary in order for others to offer you help (they 1st need to understand what the actual issue is). Hang in there.

Comment: Are you invoking scapy as root?  `sudo scapy`

Comment: One more thing: please copy and paste code, output, and diagnostics into the question as *text*. Images are very inconvenient for readers.

Answer (score 9):

That probably would happen if you use VM or Windows Subsystem for Linux. Try standard installation, that solved the same problem for me.

Comment: Correct: you can't open a L2-raw socket directly in Python on Windows, therefore Scapy use workarounds ([Win]pcap providers) to bypass this rule.